# PHP Counting time in second

Tags: php, date, time, count, format

I have looks like simple task, but I can't solve the problem. I would like to count two times in seconds by PHP ($time + $time1) but my result is +1hour (+1day). Why?

```
$hours="00";
$minutes="34";
$seconds="13";

$hours1="00"; 
$minutes1="35";
$seconds1="11";

$time=($hours*3600)+($minutes*60)+$seconds; // 2053 seconds
$time1=($hours1*3600)+($minutes1*60)+$seconds1; // 2111 seconds

$sum=$time+$time1; // 4164 seconds

$format=date('H:i:s', $time); // 01:34:13
$format1=date('H:i:s', $time1); // 01:35:11
$formatsum=date('H:i:s', $sum); // 02:09:24
```

$format has to be **00**:34:13 not **01**:34:13
If I add the days date(' d H:i:s', $time); result is **01** **01**:34:13
My task is 00:34:13 + 00:35:11 with result 01:09:24 not **02**:09:24
Do I something wrong with time formating? Why it gives me +1day and +1hour to the result?

Comment: Second parameter of [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function is timestamp not only seconds..

Comment: @Mohammad Hamedani what is the meaning of timestamp ? do you know ?

Comment: Timestamp means unix timestamp that is  the number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on January 1, 1970. But i test your code and it's works only by second! I answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$format=date('H:i:s', $time); // 01:34:13
$format1=date('H:i:s', $time1); // 01:35:11
$formatsum=date('H:i:s', $sum); // 02:09:24
```

To:

```
$format=gmdate('H:i:s', $time); // 00:34:13
$format1=gmdate('H:i:s', $time1); // 00:35:11
$formatsum=gmdate('H:i:s', $sum); // 01:09:24
```

**gmdate** — Format a GMT/UTC date/time

[php doca gmdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should check your time zone. The time calculated is by your local time zone. As example, for

```
$time=($hours*3600)+($minutes*60)+$seconds; // 2053 seconds
$format=date('H:i:s', $time); // 02:34:13
```

For +2GMT

Answer (score 0):

The result is `01:34:13`, because your default timezone is set to UTC +1. 
Use `gmdate()` function instead of `date()` if you want to convert a timestamp to a UTC date:

```
$hours = "00";
$minutes = "34";
$seconds = "13";

$hours1 = "00";
$minutes1 = "35";
$seconds1 = "11";

$time = ($hours * 3600) + ($minutes * 60) + $seconds; // 2053 seconds
$time1 = ($hours1 * 3600) + ($minutes1 * 60) + $seconds1; // 2111 seconds

$sum = $time + $time1; // 4164 seconds

$format = gmdate('H:i:s', $time); // 00:34:13
$format1 = gmdate('H:i:s', $time1); // 00:35:11
$formatsum = gmdate('H:i:s', $sum); // 01:09:24
```

Also, I'm not sure what you want to achieve with your code, but there are better tools for date/time manipulation than manual addition of seconds. Check out [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes from PHP standard library.

Comment: upvoted because i feel your answer exact right, but you should also give OP updated code according to your answer